# Ubuntu 14.04 + Gnome 3.10 'Alt + Shift' shortcut doesn't work

Tags: gnome, 14.04

I just installed fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and I've found that shortcut combination 'Alt + Shift' to which I used to doesn't work.

I can successfully switch keyboard layout with 'Super + Space' shortcut combination but it is inconvenient for me.

[image: Shortcuts config]
I can see shortcuts on this screen and it seems that I should set 'Alt + Shift' to 'Switch to next source' but not to 'Modifiers-only switch to next source' BUT it is impossible to assign this shortcut to that property.

I've seen some people can fix it with this [13.10 path](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/modifier-only-input-switch) but it doesn't work for me.

In fact when I press 'Alt + Shift' it changes current language here: [image: Language indicator] but when I type it types with previously selected language.

What can I do about this? I assume there should be a way to edit some config file to assign custom shortcut or maybe there another patch for 14.04.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue but on ***Ubuntu Gnome 15.04***. It's very weird that such basic things don't work ***out-of-box*** in mid-2015 in one of the most user-friendly Linux-based OS. Even in ***Fedora 21*** it does work, but they have another trick: "no private drivers madness"...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix something similar by using the dconf editor.  For me it was Alt-F6 that had a preceding entry in org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings.